# Unable to remove cast event handler

Tags: c#, events

I have a design pattern (not sure if this is a commonly used DP, if someone has a name for it please let me know) where I have have a non-generic and a generic interface for a class. The implementation stores generic values and implements the generics interface implicitly. It also explicitly implements the non-generic interface with each property returning the value of the generic property suitably cast to its non-generic form. This works really well for properties, but I am having a few issues getting it to work quite as nicely for events.

Below is a greatly simplified version of what I am doing. The idea is that adding handlers to either interfaces version of Event should add it to the same event so that when the event fires it doesn't matter how it was subscribed to. The test code in Main shows that the event handler is not being removed as I would expect. What is the correct code for adding to/removing from Event using INormalInterface.Event's add/remove blocks?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        INormalInterface x = new ImplementingClass<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Created x and invoking...");
        x.InvokeEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Adding event and invoking...");
        x.Event += x_Event;
        x.InvokeEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Removing event and invoking...");
        x.Event -= x_Event;
        x.InvokeEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void x_Event(object sender, NormalEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Handled!");
    }
}

interface INormalInterface
{
    event EventHandler<NormalEventArgs> Event;

    void InvokeEvent();
}

interface IGenericInterface<T> : INormalInterface
{
    new event EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>> Event;
}

class ImplementingClass<T> : IGenericInterface<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>> Event;
    event EventHandler<NormalEventArgs> INormalInterface.Event
    {
        add { Event += new EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>(value); }
        remove { Event -= new EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>(value); }
    }

    public void InvokeEvent()
    {
        if (Event != null)
        {
            Event(this, new GenericEventArgs<T>());
        }
    }
}

class NormalEventArgs : EventArgs
{
}

class GenericEventArgs<T> : NormalEventArgs
{
}
```

I figure the issue is because I am 'new'ing the delegate each time so it won't resolve to the same value when adding/removing, is there a way to cast delegates? I do have one solution but it requires having a field for each event, so would appreciate any solutions that avoids this:

```
class ImplementingClass<T> : IGenericInterface<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<EventHandler<NormalEventArgs>, EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>> m_eventDictionary = new Dictionary<EventHandler<NormalEventArgs>, EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>>();

    public event EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>> Event;
    event EventHandler<NormalEventArgs> INormalInterface.Event
    {
        add { Event += m_eventDictionary[value] = new EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>(value); }
        remove { Event -= m_eventDictionary[value]; }
    }

    public void InvokeEvent()
    {
        if (Event != null)
        {
            Event(this, new GenericEventArgs<T>());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick, but I wouldn't call it pretty:

```
    event EventHandler<NormalEventArgs> INormalInterface.Event
    {
        add
        {
            var handler = (EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>), value.Target, value.Method);
            Event += handler;
        }
        remove
        {
            var handler = (EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>), value.Target, value.Method);
            Event -= handler;
        }
    }
```

The issue with

```
    add { Event += new EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>(value); }
```

is that it creates a delegate for the Delegate.Invoke method, so it cannot find a match in the event's multicast delegate. Is that, and not the creation of a new object itself, that prevents you from removing the handler.

Comment: I'll settle for a not pretty solution if it works. The thing that makes this so ugly though is having to specify the type twice, it would be nice if there was a generic version of this function on the delegate type, i.e.:`Delegate.CreateDelegate<EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>>(value.Target, value.Method)`and returned the correct type. Specifying something twice is a bit of a maintainance nightmare.

Comment: Delegate.CreateDelegate is a static method, so you could create your own generic static utility method and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**

Not the prettiest, but this seems to do the trick:

```
    event EventHandler<NormalEventArgs> INormalInterface.Event
    {
        add { Event += new EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>(value); }
        remove
        {
            var d = Event.GetInvocationList().First(x => x.Target.GetHashCode() == value.GetHashCode());
            Event -= (EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>>) d;
        }
    }
```

**Original Answer:**

---

It seems to me that you have your interfaces around the wrong way - unless you have an existing reason for it, I would change it to be like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IGenericInterface<int> x = new ImplementingClass<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Created x and invoking...");
        x.InvokeEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Adding event and invoking...");
        x.Event += x_Event;
        x.InvokeEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Removing event and invoking...");
        x.Event -= x_Event;
        x.InvokeEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void x_Event(object sender, NormalEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Handled!");
    }
}

interface IBaseInterface<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<T> Event;

    void InvokeEvent();
}

interface INormalInterface : IBaseInterface<NormalEventArgs>
{
}

interface IGenericInterface<T> : IBaseInterface<GenericEventArgs<T>>
{
}

class ImplementingClass<T> : IGenericInterface<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<T>> Event;

    public void InvokeEvent()
    {
        if (Event != null)
        {
            Event(this, new GenericEventArgs<T>());
        }
    }
}

class NormalEventArgs : EventArgs
{
}

class GenericEventArgs<T> : NormalEventArgs
{
}
```

Comment: There are existing reasons for me having the interfaces that way round. As I said, this is greatly simplified example; I have all sorts of properties that return generic types and want to be able to pass my class to methods that both care about the exact types, along with methods that don't care/can't know about the types being returned.

Comment: Actually, this may work, I was a little wary that I might end up with long list of generic parameters in my base interface, give me a moment to test it with my real world (more complex) code and see if I can get it working.

Comment: I will see if I can come up with something else too then!

Comment: @BykerDave added in a way to do it with your existing code structure.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I don't think there is a 'pretty' solution :(. I was thinking about your interface rearranging solution, I don't think I would ever be able to use INormalInterface because ImplementingClass does not implement it I can't cast x to it, or am I missing something?

Comment: @BykerDave that is correct, as in my version `INormalInterface` and `IGenericInterface<>` are siblings, you cannot cast between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the observer pattern could be used here http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DoFactory.GangOfFour.Observer.RealWorld
{
  /// <summary>
  /// MainApp startup class for Real-World
  /// Observer Design Pattern.
  /// </summary>
  class MainApp
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point into console application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
      // Create IBM stock and attach investors
      IBM ibm = new IBM("IBM", 120.00);
      ibm.Attach(new Investor("Sorros"));
      ibm.Attach(new Investor("Berkshire"));

      // Fluctuating prices will notify investors
      ibm.Price = 120.10;
      ibm.Price = 121.00;
      ibm.Price = 120.50;
      ibm.Price = 120.75;

      // Wait for user
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'Subject' abstract class
  /// </summary>
  abstract class Stock
  {
    private string _symbol;
    private double _price;
    private List<IInvestor> _investors = new List<IInvestor>();

    // Constructor
    public Stock(string symbol, double price)
    {
      this._symbol = symbol;
      this._price = price;
    }

    public void Attach(IInvestor investor)
    {
      _investors.Add(investor);
    }

    public void Detach(IInvestor investor)
    {
      _investors.Remove(investor);
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
      foreach (IInvestor investor in _investors)
      {
        investor.Update(this);
      }

      Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    // Gets or sets the price
    public double Price
    {
      get { return _price; }
      set
      {
        if (_price != value)
        {
          _price = value;
          Notify();
        }
      }
    }

    // Gets the symbol
    public string Symbol
    {
      get { return _symbol; }
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'ConcreteSubject' class
  /// </summary>
  class IBM : Stock
  {
    // Constructor
    public IBM(string symbol, double price)
      : base(symbol, price)
    {
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'Observer' interface
  /// </summary>
  interface IInvestor
  {
    void Update(Stock stock);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'ConcreteObserver' class
  /// </summary>
  class Investor : IInvestor
  {
    private string _name;
    private Stock _stock;

    // Constructor
    public Investor(string name)
    {
      this._name = name;
    }

    public void Update(Stock stock)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Notified {0} of {1}'s " +
        "change to {2:C}", _name, stock.Symbol, stock.Price);
    }

    // Gets or sets the stock
    public Stock Stock
    {
      get { return _stock; }
      set { _stock = value; }
    }
  }
}
```